# Various ways of asynchronously returning a collection (with C# 7 features)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, system.reactive

I have a simple synchronous method, looking like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> MyMethod(Source src)
{
    // returns a List of Oof objects from a web service
    var oofs = src.LoadOofsAsync().Result; 
    foreach(var oof in oofs)
    {
         // transforms an Oof object to a Foo object
         yield return Transform(oof); 
    }
}
```

Since the method is part of a web application, it is good to use all resources as effectively as possible. Therefore, I would like to change the method into an *asynchronous* one. The easiest option is to do something like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Foo>> MyMethodAsync(Source src)
{
    var oofs = await src.LoadOofsAsync();
    return oofs.Select(oof => Transform(oof));
}
```

I am not an expert on either `async`/`await` or `IEnumerable`. However, from what I understand, using this approach "kills" the benefits of `IEnumerable`, because the Task is awaited until the whole collection is loaded, thus omitting the "laziness" of the `IEnumerable` collection.

On other StackOverflow posts I have read several suggestions for using [Rx.NET](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) (or System.Reactive). Quickly browsing through the documentation I have read that `IObservable<T>` is their asynchronous alternative to `IEnumerable<T>`. However, using the naive approach and trying to type the following just did not work:

```
public async IObservable<Foo> MyMethodReactive(Source src)
{
    var oofs = await src.LoadOofsAsync();
    foreach(var oof in oofs)
    {
        yield return Transform(oof);
    }
}
```

I got an compilation error, that `IObservable<T>` does implement neither `GetEnumerator()`, nor `GetAwaiter()` - thus it cannot use both `yield` and `async`. I have not read the documentation of Rx.NET deeper, so I am probably just using the library incorrectly. But I did not want to spend time learning a new framework to modify a single method.

With the new [possibilities in C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types) it is now possible to implement custom types. Thus I, theoretically, could implement an `IAsyncEnumerable`, which would define both `GetEnumerator()` and `GetAwaiter()` methods. However, from my previous experience, I remember an unsuccessful attempt to create a custom implementation of `GetEnumerator()`... I ended up with a simple List, hidden in a container.

Thus we have 4 possible approaches to solve the task:

1. Keep the code synchronous, but with `IEnumerable`
2. Change it to asynchronous, but wrap `IEnumerable` in a `Task<T>`
3. Learn and use Rx.NET (System.Reactive)
4. Create a custom `IAsyncEnumerable` with C# 7 features

What are the benefits and drawbacks of each of these attempts? Which of them has the most significant impact on resource utilization?

Comment: There is also a very easy 5th way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq: `AsParallel()`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti  Is AsParallel suitable with I/O-bound tasks though?

Comment: If you are concerned about "killing" benefits, what you really should be worried about is `src.LoadOofsAsync()` -- that *already* returns a `Task<IEnumerable<Oof>>`. Wrapping some more asynchrony over that isn't going to help, unless `Transform` is actually costly and can meaningfully be parallelized/waited on.

Comment: @JeroenMostert If `LoadOofsAsync` isn't awaited in `MyMethod` it will block the thread no mater how costly Transform is.

Comment: @Magnus: my point is that whatever technique is being considered to make `MyMethod` "good"/"better" should ideally also be applied to `LoadOofsAsync`, or at least considered there first. There is a big difference between a solution that is truly streaming, and cutting initial processing time in half (although that's certainly not useless).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, good point. However, I actually have a couple of other methods. Some of them await just a single value, but generate a whole sequence of results. I am trying to find a single pattern that would help me to change all synchronous methods into asynchronous ones, while keeping the code consistent.

Comment: There is no single such pattern because it depends on your needs. In particular, applying `Observable` (which is the closest thing to a completely asynchronous enumeration) has considerable consequences for the rest of your code base (not to mention a learning curve). An `IAsyncEnumerator` that has a `MoveNextAsync` is implemented by some projects, but has the drawback of not supporting all existing enumeration operations (or something simple like `foreach`). It's a balancing act between simple and maximally responsive/cool.

Comment: @Magnus No, currently not. However, this "asynchronization" is a part of a larger process, where our team is investigating the possibilities of using WebSockets, PUSH services and a couple of IoT protocols. Our goal is to study the available technologies and pick the best one, which would be later used in other products by other teams. Currently, we are also studying SignalR 3. If it was able to send items from IEnumerable one by one, the laziness would be a major factor, as well.

Comment: @lss - If you're using "WebSockets, PUSH services and a couple of IoT protocols" or "SignalR" then using Rx to expose those services is an excellent idea.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, however this question requires more understanding of async design. IMO, you dont mix your Async patterns. If you are a pull program then you use task (async/await), if you are a push program, then Rx (IObservable) can be a good option. However this also then means that your web app should be push (websocket, Azure IoT etc) and is your Datastore also streaming? So to @JeroenMostert's point, what ever you apply to `MyMethod` will impact the desing of `LoadOofsAsync` and vice-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Keep the code synchronous, but with IEnumerable
> - Change it to asynchronous, but wrap IEnumerable in a Task
> - Learn and use Rx.NET (System.Reactive)
> - Create a custom IAsyncEnumerable with C# 7 features
>
> What are the benefits and drawbacks of each of these attempts? Which
>   of them has the most significant impact on resource utilization?

In your situation, it sounds like the best option is `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`. Here's what where each option excels:

1. Synchronous code (or parallel synchronous code) excels when there is no I/O, but heavy CPU use. If you have I/O code waiting synchronously (like your first method implementation), the CPU is just burning cycles while waiting for the web service to respond doing nothing.
2. `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` is meant for when there is an I/O operation to fetch a collection. The thread running waiting for the I/O operation can then have something else scheduled on it while awaiting. 
   This sounds like your case.
3. Rx is best for push scenarios: Where there is data being 'pushed' to your code which you want to respond to. Common examples are applications that receive stock-market pricing data, or chat applications.
4. `IAsyncEnumerable` is meant for when you have a collection where each item will require or generate an async task. An example: Iterating over a collection of items and executing some sort of unique DB query for each one. If your `Transform` was in fact an I/O-bound async method, then this is probably more sensible.